# Is it necessary or beneficial to use a "stuff.whatever" naming convention in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, naming-conventions

I'm working on a MySQL database for a social network site I'm building, and so far it's been a great learning experience.  However, there has been one thing in particular that's always confused me.

When seeking answers to a particular issue, I see so many examples that use dots in their naming conventions in their MySQL queries.  For example:

```
SELECT c.id, c.comment, c.user_id, u.username, u.photo
FROM (comments c)
JOIN users u ON c.user_id = u.id
WHERE c.topic_id = 9
```

and here is another example:

```
SELECT fb.auto_id, fb.user_id, fb.bulletin, fb.subject, fb.color, fb.submit_date, fru.disp_name, fru.pic_url
FROM friend_bulletin AS fb
LEFT JOIN friend_friend AS ff ON fb.user_id = ff.userid
LEFT JOIN friend_reg_user AS fru ON fb.user_id = fru.auto_id
WHERE (
ff.friendid =1
AND ff.status =1
)
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Is there a particular benefit to using the dots in the names?  As someone who comes from doing a lot of CSS work, at first glance the dots appear to me as some kind of association between different things, but what are they for here?

I suppose I just want to make sure I'm not making my database structure/queries less efficient by not using this 'dot' naming convention.  If someone could explain to me in laymen's terms what they are used for, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

`stuff.whatever` should be thought of as `table_name.column_name`. You're explicitly associating each column reference with the table it belongs to which, IMHO, is a best practice to follow.

Comment: @RedFilter Correct.Whether the full table name or the alias is used, the concept is the same.

Comment: @Joe, That's kinda what I thought, but what if you select the column with `SELECT column_name` and then the table with `FROM table_name`.  If you use `SELECT table_name.column_name`, what purpose would you have for using `FROM`?  I'm still quite confused.

Comment: @vertigoelectric Are you trying to say the `FROM` clause should not be required simply because you've fully qualified the column in the `SELECT`? That just violates basic SQL syntax.

Comment: You need the FROM clause because if you're selecting from more than one table then you are performing a join, and therefore you need to specify what type of join and what the join condition is.

Comment: @Joe, No, I'm not suggesting that.  Quite the opposite, actually. What purpose does one have in specifying `SELECT table_name.column_name` if they're specifying the table name using `FROM`?  It seems redundant to me and I'd like to know the benefit of using something like `SELECT table_name.column_name`.

Comment: @vertigoelectric: Personally, I find it a good practice that makes the code more readable. It also prevents "ambiguous column" errors when the same column name is used in more than one table of the query.

Comment: @Hammerite, I suppose I need to learn more about `JOIN` and how that works, then.  I know it has something to do with combining tables or something, but I'm not sure what I would use it for...

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't think of the dots as being part of a "naming convention."  The functionality is more similar to calling an attribute on an object.

In the case of `stuff.whatever` 'stuff'
represents the database table and 
`whatever` represents the data in a column called 'whatever' in the database.

If you've seen a column referenced without the table portion, it is because the user is expecting mysql to figure out which column they mean.

If there is only one table in the query with a column of that name, mysql can do it, no problem.

But, for example, you have a "facebook" table and a "twitter" table and you join them through a query because they both have a "user_id" column or something, and they BOTH have an "avatar_image" column and you didn't specify the table, mysql would raise en error telling you it didn't know exactly what you were asking for.

Comment: Okay, so I think I'm understanding how it works.  Is there any specific benefit to doing it this way, though?  In all my my work so far, I just use `SELECT column FROM table`.  Wouldn't that essentially do the same thing?  Also, in the examples above, the person used both the dot association AND the `FROM` clause, which seems redundant to me if the purpose of the dot association is to specify which table it's from in the first place.  See where I might get confused here?

Comment: I do not believe that there is a performance benefit at all.

They do essentially the same thing, unless a table your joining on has a column of the same name, for example:

Pet
-id
-name
-owner_id

Owner
-id
-name

`SELECT name FROM pet LEFT JOIN owner ON owner.id = pet.owner_id`

will cause an error, mysql will say:
`Column 'name' in field list is ambiguous

if you told mysql that you wanted the owner name:

`SELECT owner.name FROM pet LEFT JOIN owner ON owner.id = pet.owner_id`

it works, just like if you use aliases

`SELECT o.name FROM pet p LEFT JOIN owner o ON owner.id = pet.owner_id`

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with using full name conventions, however, if you have long `table`, `field` names, it is easier to use alias for readability purpose.

Comment: I keep hearing the term "alias" for table names.  Could you explain this to me in more detail, please?  In the first example I posted, the person uses `c.comment` and `u.username`.  Are the `c` and `u` examples of a table alias, and if so, how do you set them?